# Iterate through multiple sheets in excel file and filter all the data after a value in a row and append all the sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with around 50 sheets. All the data in the excel file looks like below:

[image]

I want to read the first row and all the rows after 'finish' in the first column.

I have written my script as something like this.

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel1_all_data.xlsx')
df = df.head(1).append(df[df.index>df.iloc[:,0] == 'finish'].index[0]+1])
```

The output looks like below:
[image]

The start and finish are gone.
My question is - How can I iterate through all the sheets in a similar way and append them into one dataframe? Also have a column which is the sheet name please.
The data in other sheets is similar too, but will have different dates and Names. But start and finish will still be present and we want to get everything after 'finish'.

Thank you so much for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and let me know if if it works for you :

```
import pandas as pd

wbSheets = pd.ExcelFile("excel1_all_data.xlsx").sheet_names
frames = []

for st in wbSheets:
    df = pd.read_excel("excel1_all_data.xlsx",st)
    frames.append(df.iloc[[0]])
    frames.append(df[5:])

res = pd.concat(frames)
print(res)
```

The pd.ExcelFile("excel1_all_data.xlsx").sheet_names is what will get you the sheet you need to iterate.

In [Pandas.read_excel's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)! you'll find that you can read a specific sheet of the workbook. Which I've used in the for loop.

I don't know if concat is the best way to solve this for huge files but it worked fine on my sample.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That works sir, thank you. I just changed the df[5:] part though as it is not consistent across all tabs.